# ¿Cómo detener la ejecución del comando "ionic serve" en la consola?

Tags: ionic, consola

Mi consola es MINGW64 y trabajando con ionic, cuando escribo `ionic serve` para probar mi app en el navegador luego no puedo introducir más comandos, es como si se quedara ejecutando algo. ¿Cómo puedo salir?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Escribo letras al azar le doy a enter y no responde...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para detener la ejecución de este comando debes presionar:

> ctrl + c

en tu consola, en el caso de necesitar ejecutar otros comandos mientras ionic serve se esta ejecutando debes abrir otra ventana de consola en tu directorio.